# How do I deploy an existing sqlite file on an iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have a legacy sqlite file on my iPhone app, but when tested on-device the sqlite file can not be found. Is there some method to deploy the sqlite file on the iPhone device?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you paste the code you are using to load the file from your application bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file needs to be added to your Xcode project.  Make sure you are loading the correct file and there are no typos.

**EDIT:** Update based on comments:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sqlitefile" ofType:@"db"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    // Don't create new sqlite file
}
else {
    // Create a new sqlite file
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zsnow, but this file was added in my project and it's on list file to be packed, then when debug the source code, a new sqlite file is created. It's possible drop sqlite file when deployed in the correct path?

Comment: Hi, Zsnow your code works. My error was looking for the sqlite file, putting full name on `pathResource:DB_NAME`, I was using a constant macro `#define DB_NAME (@"myfile.sqlite")"`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the faded green checkmark next to it.